# Arcore session reset

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

How do I reset the AR session? I found a solution to this in one of the issues, where the solution was to restart the activity, but that will not work for me because I am using the arfragment in one of the fragments in navigation view, so I tried resetting the fragment but the variables don't reset, which I can take care of by resetting them manually(a solution I found on stackoverflow). I was wondering if there was a better solution to this where I can just reset the session, without restarting the activity or the fragment the ARFragment is in. By "resetting session" I mean, return the ArFragment to the way it was when the app starts, no planes, no anchors, no node, where it shows the handmotion.

Comment: In Unity it is possible by disabling ARCore device component which disables ARCoreSession if that is somehow helpful to you. This applies to Unity so this is the reason why I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?